# IE11 - How to update screen when stepping through javascript code in debugger

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

When using IE11 developer toolbar how can you get the page to update its rendering whilst stepping through code?

Comment: Best way: Don't use IE for debugging XD
I'm sorry, I couldn't resist. Chrome has FAR better debugging capabilities than IE does.

Comment: In all seriousness, I was thinking the screen DID update when stepping through the code....?

Comment: IE11 is a big improvement in dev tools. Doesn't the play button do the trick? I'm doing IE9 debugging in IE11 as we speak, and it seems to do exactly that.

Comment: "Play" will simply run the code, it will not allow you to step through it any more. I am debugging in IE11 and I see what the OP is referring to. I am not at all impressed with IE's developer tools. @Ryan, is there ANY way you can use Chrome instead?

Comment: @derstrom8 thanks a bunch - hand't thought of that. Or maybe I am debugging a problem that only happens on IE11? Just waiting for someone to come along and tell me that I just have to tell the end user not to use IE11. If only I could...

Comment: @derstrom8 - sorry for my sense of humour failure. IE will do that to ya!

Comment: Haha sorry for the delay, I was at work and had to go home for the day. I meant that the debugging alone could be done in Chrome, just to make sure there weren't any obvious mistakes. I don't suppose you'd be willing to show us the code that's causing the problem? I have found that browsers like chrome and FF are much more tolerant of, say, errant commas than IE is. It could be a simple mistake that debugging may or may not even help